# How to bundle my monorepo poetry subproject into an executable?

Tags: python, docker, monorepo, python-poetry

I have a monorepo with multiple poetry projects.

They may depend on each other with the usual path dependencies of poetry (i.e `{path='../some-lib',develop=true}`).

During development everything works ok (not like a charm, but ok).

When bundling it all, I assume dependencies must be copied into the virtual env (not referenced), so that I can copy maybe some folder or something, into the docker image.

I don't want to copy the whole monorepo into the docker image, at least not the final image (I can use staged build where first I copy it all, and then I copy only the executable). Yet... I don't know how!

Comment: "Bundle [a Python project] into an executable" is a bad idea. Don't do it when you don't have to, and this is certainly a case where you don't have to.

Comment: The general means for installing Python projects, akin to `pip install`, doesn't involve creation of any executables at all -- each module is installed as a separate file (maybe with .pyc and .pyo files as well), and then the entrypoints have wrapper scripts programmatically created. That's what you want: it means that when your distro applies a security patch to Python or its dependencies, the program you installed gets that patch; it means that when libpython is already loaded into memory, that copy can be reused; it means that the python executable is already decompressed and ready to mmap

Comment: whereas when you build a single-file executable (with cx_freeze, or freeze, or pyinstaller, or any of the other competing projects), what you get is a bunch of .pyc files and supporting DLLs packed into an installer, which then often (depending on details of your dependency chain) needs to unpack contents into a temporary directory and invoke a new executable there. That's fragile (it may not work at all if your tmpfs is set noexec), it's slow to start, it's memory-hungry, it means you have multiple copies of native executables and libraries, and it's generally bad news.

Comment: Part of the whole _point_ of Docker is that it provides an abstraction layer that lets a container that consists of any number of files be addressed as a single entrypoint. Lean on that; `pip install` is your friend (assuming your pyproject.toml is set up to allow its use with a poetry project).

Comment: (Also, that single-file executable doesn't do as much as you might expect to prevent reverse-engineering; it's pretty darned easy to pull the individual .pyc files out, at which point the Python `dis` module disassembles them just fine; there've also historically been very effective decompilation stacks for Python bytecode as well).

Comment: Ok @CharlesDuffy, maybe just bundling a whole independent virtual env (it can be a folder)... possible?

Comment: You can _absolutely_ install into a virtualenv while building your Docker image, yes, and indeed that's the approach I'd recommend.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: If you've done the appropriate adjustments in your `pyproject.toml`, activate the virtualenv and run `pip install .` from the source tree. Granted, `develop=True` for intra-tree dependencies makes things a little weird and might throw a wrench in the works, but if it _actually does_ cause problems, that would be a great topic for a question with a [mre] demonstrating those problems.